# What is the purpose for the ui.router.router sub-module?

Tags: angular-ui-router

I found this in the ui-router documents recently:

**ui.router.router sub-module**

*This module is a dependency of other sub-modules. Do not include this module as a dependency in your angular app (use ui.router module instead).*

So what exactly is the purpose for this sub-module then and what is the use case for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing is the use case. As it appears, UI Router [has a hierarchy of modules](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/0.2.15/src/common.js#L222) that can be tested separately.

In the case of `ui.router.router` this means that [its components are tested](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/0.2.15/test/urlRouterSpec.js) apart from parent modules (i.e. `ui.router.state`).